# Swift base64 image encoding with EXIF data

Tags: ios, swift, base64, exif

I am currently using base64 encoding to convert and sent multiple images in a JSON file from my Swift app to my API using:

```
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
let sSideL = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

While extending my API, I now would like to use the rich EXIF data provided by most smartphones like lense information, field of view or the **device model**. Most important for my current purpose is the `"Image Model"` tag, in order to identify the device, which took the picture.

I recognized that there are some EXIF data left in the `base64` data coming through my API but it is limited to the orientation and very basic information like the orientation. Also when I directly print the base64String in Xcode and analyze it, it has very poor EXIF information. Technically it should be possible, because converting the same image in an [online base64 converter](https://www.browserling.com/tools/image-to-base64) and analyzing the returning string, I am able to see EXIF information like "Image Model", etc.

Is there a way to convert my UIImage to a base64 string keeping all EXIF details?

The API represents the main part of my system, so I would like to keep it as simple as possible and not add additional upload parameter.

**EDIT**
Here my code to capture the UIImage

```
extension CameraController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {


    public func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                        resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Swift.Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            // ERROR
        }
        else if let buffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let data = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: buffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: nil),
            let image = UIImage(data: data) {

            // SEND IMAGE TO SERVER
        }
        else {
            // UNKNOWN ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The EXIF data isn't lost during the base64 encoding, it wasn't in the imageData in the first place. Where are you getting the UIImage from?

Comment: Hey @Marcel! Thanks for your reply. I updated the question with the `AVCapturePhotoCapture` code. Do you think the EXIF data gets lost there?

Comment: The issue is that you are converting the jpeg data to UIImage before sending to the server. Thats where you discarded the exif data. You need to send the data returned from `jpegPhotoDataRepresentation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the newer (iOS 11+) delegate method:

```
    public func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            if let error = error {
        // ERROR
            } else if let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {

        // SEND IMAGE DATA TO SERVER
    }
    else {
        // UNKNOWN ERROR
    }
}
```

or the method you are using:

```
    public func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                    resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Swift.Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        // ERROR
    } else if let buffer = photoSampleBuffer,
        let data = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: buffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: nil) {
        // SEND IMAGE DATA TO SERVER
    }
    else {
        // UNKNOWN ERROR
    }
}
```

Like leo-dabus mentioned, you need to send the image data to the server, that has the metadata in it. If you first create an UIImage and convert that back again to data, you have lost the metadata.

Comment: Marcel one quick further question - the pure data from the AVCapturePhotoOutput keeps the EXIF data intact but when I try to resize the converted UIImage and convert it back into data, the EXIF data is gone. I tried to use the CGImage, JPEG and PNG method but none of them keeps the EXIF data intact. Also without resizing no UIImage-to-data method works properly.